# add items properties - c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, fileinfo

I'd like to load the multiple files (like Images, Documents, Pdfs) to the listview and along its properties will be displayed.

This was the code I am working with:

```
        FileInfo FInfo;

        DialogResult dr = this.openFD.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Read the files
            foreach (String file in openFD.FileNames)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
                item.Tag = file;

                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Images, Word Documents(excel, word, ppt, etc), PDF

Comment: Do you mean the attributes of the property?  Such as creationdate and file size?

Comment: yes like that and its type. like the details shown in explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way I do for Excel files. You just need to modify it a bit. I am hoping this helps.

```
    private void loadMatchingResponsesReports()
    {
        listBox2.Items.Clear();

        string[] list = getMatchingReports();
        foreach (String S in list)
        {
            FileInfo fileResponse = new FileInfo(S);
            string fileResponseNameOnly = fileResponse.Name;
            listBox2.Items.Add(fileResponseNameOnly);
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    public string[] getMatchingReports()
    {
        string[] returnR = null;
        try
        {
            returnR = Directory.GetFiles(textBox3.Text + @"\", "*.xls");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't get some files from directory " + textBox3.Text);
        }
        return returnR;
    }
```

Comment: i used '.CreationTime'. what should be the code to call the size?

Comment: @kazu.zushifukato, [MSDN is your friend: FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx). Size.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a simple string, you might want to use a custom object to store all properties you want associated with the ListViewItem.

`item.Tag = file;`

`file` should be of custom type, a `Dictionary<string, string>` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class. For each file you want to add, construct an instance. It as has all the properties you would want to add to an explorer like interface such as: CreationTime, Extension, Name etc. You get the size (in bytes) from the [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) property.

You would add a [ListViewSubItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.aspx) for each attribute, corresponding to the column in your ListView.